# How to debud django crontab?

Tags: python, django, cron, django-cron

I have setup a cron job by using django crontab. As per defined in documentation I defined a test job in cron.py and defined it to run in 1 minute interval in settings.py.

```
#cron.py
def test_cron_run():
    print("\n\nHello World....!! ",timezone.now())

#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'material.theme.cyan',
    'material',
    'material.admin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'django_crontab',
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'myapp.cron.test_cron_run','>>'+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'log/debug7.log')),
]
```

I have added the cron jobs by running `python3 manage.py crontab add`.
Also the job is added as I can see if I run, `python3 manage.py crontab show`
However I cannot see any log file being generated.
Is there any way to debug this, the os logs or something?

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing a space after the `>>`?

Comment: what if using `('*/1 * * * *', 'myapp.cron.test_cron_run', '>> test.log'),` instead?

Comment: Yes it runs if I run it forcefully by run command passing the hash value of the job and prints on console, however no log file generated, anyway, is there a way I can hook a debugger to my code to debug my django code?

Answer (score 5):

To combine the tips given here, this is how it worked for me:

```
import os

CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'myapp.cron.test_cron_run', '>> ' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'log/debug7.log' + ' 2>&1 '))
]
```

Additional notes

- The directory needs to exist and you need write permission
- After each change of CRONJOBS, run `python3 manage.py crontab add` twice
- Without the `2>&1`, error messages from python are not logged as they are written to STDERR
- Check what is actually written to your crontab with `crontab -l`
- If it is not working, you may have a mail from cron. Depending on your system, read it with `mail`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just try adding `2>&1` at the end of you cron job, it will redirect the error output to the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I could only get it to work by including the direct path to the logfile and creating it ahead of time

Comment: Even though, the file had automatically being created, nothing was being written to it. The solution is as you mentioned to create the file yourself.